# Mysql Rank/Lead Equivalent from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, rank

Below is MSSQL. I am trying to find a MySQL equivalent for the query below:

```
select distinct inv.name as InvName  

    ,slotapproval.value 
    ,rank() over (partition by inv.name,slots.customerid order by cast(slots.date as date) desc)  as RankDESC  
    ,rank() over (partition by inv.name,slots.customerid order by cast(slots.date as date) asc)  as RankASC    
    from slotapproval  
    INNER JOIN slots ON slots.slotid=slotapproval.slotid  
    INNER JOIN inv ON slotapproval.invid=inv.invid
```

Basically I am trying for Rank with ordering desc/Asc. Any Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Your best bet may be to switch to MySQL 8 (which is still not officially reased AFAIK) or MariaDB, which both feature window functions. Otherwise you'll have to emulate them with variables somehow I guess, which is probably difficult.

Comment: MySql's current official release lacks window functions, CTEs, lateral joins (apply), materialized views, and much more. IMO it doesn't really even qualify as a "modern" relational database, and hasn't for over a decade. The upcoming version 8 corrects _some_ of this, but if you really want an oepn source database, postgresql is in a _much_ better place, and has been for some time now.